# Matlab openGL Warning

Tags: matlab, opengl

I'm tasked with upgrading a lot of legacy models and scripts made in an older version of Matlab/Simulink and have it running smoothly in R2018b. Among other requirements I'm not allowed to have any warnings issued upon execution of .m scripts or Simulink models. This is generally tedious but straightforward to comply.

However, there is a specific warning that Matlab does not give me hints on possible sources:

> Warning: MATLAB has disabled some advanced graphics rendering features by switching to software OpenGL. For more information click **here**.

The link opens the Matlab Help page titled [Resolving Low-Level Graphics Issues](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/resolving-low-level-graphics-issues.html?searchHighlight=advanced%20graphics%20openGL%20warning&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), which describes issues I'm not finding  (or at least not noticing)

I do note that many scripts I run create and close figures, but this is done procedurally. I haven't been able to associate this warning with some specific function or feature. I'm working on a Windows Server machine.

Does anyone have an idea of how to narrow down which kind of function os Simulink block could cause this warning?

Comment: The warning is that MATLAB is not using the GPU for graphics, but CPU. If you have a GPU in your computer, and its being used for graphics (not a compute GPU) then make sure the drivers are updated and type `opengl hardware` in MATLAB, that should switch the renderer and remove the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [datenwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53207496/52738) and [Ander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207077/matlab-opengl-warning#comment93303367_53207077) point out, the first thing to try is to update your drivers. If this doesn't work, and your only problem is that you're getting the warning but your graphics still render fine, then you have two other options to try.

First, you can simply modify your OpenGL rendering preferences using [`opengl`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/opengl.html). The following will set your preference to `'software'` and save that setting for future sessions:

```
opengl('save', 'software');
```

Alternatively, you can just try to [suppress that particular warning message](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html). After you get the warning, issue this call to the [`warning`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/warning.html) function:

```
w = warning('query', 'last');
```

The `w.identifier` field will give you the ID for the warning message, which I believe will be `'MATLAB:hg:AutoSoftwareOpenGL'` in this case. You can then add the following line to your [startup.m](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file so that this warning is suppressed every time MATLAB is opened:

```
warning('off', 'MATLAB:hg:AutoSoftwareOpenGL');
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the original vendor drivers for your GPU. The drivers that are installed by Windows by default lack full OpenGL support. Download the driver package directly from the website of Intel, AMD or NVidia, depending on what GPU you have.

If you don't have GPU, for example when running in a Virtual Machine, then you can not avoid that warning, because then Matlab has no other choice than falling back on the software OpenGL implementation that it ships with.

*There's nothing you can do about that, other than making sure, that the system you're running Matlab on, does have proper OpenGL support!*

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to get it, so I'll put you here in case it helps how I managed to activate openGL in Linux:

1. If you haven't already (it's common for other problems), rename libstdc++ library from MATLAB:
   `mv _YOUR_MATLAB_ROOT_FOLDER_/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 _YOUR_MATLAB_ROOT_FOLDER_/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.bak`
2. Create this link: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/ /usr/lib/`
3. Run `export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=YOUR_DRI_DRIVER;matlab -desktop -nosoftwareopeng`
   Your DRI Driver will be a file from `/usr/lib/dri`, removing "_dri" (in my case was the "radeons" driver for an AMD Vega graphic card.
4. Run MATLAB from a terminal using: `export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=_YOUR_DRIVER_HERE_;matlab -desktop -nosoftwareopengl`. *YOUR_DRIVER_HERE* should be your driver, radeonsi in my case.
5. Check openGL with `info = rendererinfo`
6. If something went wrong, you will be able to see in the terminal which library was responsible. Executing 4) and 5) I was discovering what I had to correct, you can do the same if you have another problem that has not appeared to me.

So that it always runs correctly I put `export MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=YOUR_DRI_DRIVER` at the beginning of the script that runs matlab (_YOUR_MATLAB_FOLDER/bin/matlab), although I suppose it can also be set as an environment variable.

I hope this has been useful to you.